# Calling virtual method from base

Tags: c#, virtual-functions

I am trying to make a library for MigraDoc, based on [this example](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Invoice-sample.ashx), which supports different types of documents. My idea was to make a base class, with a virtual method for `CreatePage()` (the method responsible for the page layout). However, the concept was that `CreatePage()` should be called from a method called `CreateDocument()` which is called by the user. Alas, it will be possible to override `CreatePage()`, but it is not meant to be called directly. It will look something like this:

```
public class DocumentWriter
{
    private Document document;

    public virtual void CreateDocument(IDocumentArgs args)
    {
       document = new Document();

       DefineStyles();
       CreatePage();
       FillContent(args);
    }

    public virtual void CreatePage()
    {
        // Create page layout here
    }

    // Remaining code skipped for readability...
}
```

But if create inherited class, which overrides `CreatePage()`, then which method will be called from `CreateDocument()`?

- The original virtual (non-overridden) method
- The method which overrides `CreatePage()`

Comment: The override will be called.

Comment: if you are then creating an instance of Derived classes and calling CreateDocument, it will call overridden method only

Comment: if you don't mean to call `CreatePage()` directly from another code you can user `protected` modifier

Comment: That´s the whole point of `ovderride`, to be able to overwrite the base-implementation.  Aynway you could simply try it out yourself by writing a test-program with some virtual member and by checking which member is called, when you override it in your class.

Comment: for this kind of approach make use of template design pattern with abstract class where method will remain abstract

Comment: @PranayRana that is actually what I ended up doing. So I am happy to see it suggested by someone else :-).

Comment: @Noceo - i was about to answer but then i see you accepted answer and happy with it so not answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the method is `virtual`, the correct version will be called. The mechanism at work is called [*polymorphism*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism).

In fact `CreateDocument` does not even need to be virtual for this to work (unless you intend to override it in another base class).

You can see it at work with a [simple test program](https://www.ideone.com/cKikPA) (note that I made `CreatePage` `protected` so it cannot be called from outside `DocumentWriter` or its base classes). Note that even when I am calling `CreateDocument` explicitly through the base class type, it will always call the correct version based on the run-time type of the object.

```
public class DocumentWriter
{
    public /*virtual*/ void CreateDocument()
    {
       CreatePage();
    }

    protected virtual void CreatePage()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("DocumentWriter.CreatePage()");
    }
}

public class PdfDocumentWriter : DocumentWriter
{
    protected override void CreatePage()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("PdfDocumentWriter.CreatePage()");
    }
}

public class HtmlDocumentWriter : DocumentWriter
{
    protected override void CreatePage()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("HtmlDocumentWriter.CreatePage()");
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DocumentWriter documentWriter = new PdfDocumentWriter();
        documentWriter.CreateDocument();

        // Re-use the same variable. 
        // CreateDocumentwill still call the correct version of CreatePage.
        documentWriter = new HtmlDocumentWriter();
        documentWriter.CreateDocument();
    }
}
```

This prints

```
PdfDocumentWriter.CreatePage()
HtmlDocumentWriter.CreatePage()
```

as expected.

Comment: Thank you for very understandable answer. I will make the base function non-virtual (since this should not be overridden) and only allow overriding the sub-methods.